# I want to navigate to the home screen without using drawer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

Is there a way for the navigation to go directly to the home screen rather than pop(drawer) while passing the string properties below?

The `cityName` property can't be passed using pushNamed.
Please let me know if there is a way

Can I use something other than navigator.pop in onpressed?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../const.dart';

class CityScreen extends StatelessWidget {
static const String routeName = '/cityScreen';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _mycontroller = TextEditingController();
    String cityName;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/city.jpg'),
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6), BlendMode.dstATop),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, size: 30),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: 'Enter City Name'),
                  controller: _mycontroller,
                  autofocus: true,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                   cityName = value;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, cityName);
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Click here',
                  style: kbuttonStyle,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments in pushReplacementNamed/pushNamed as well like this:

```
 Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
      context,
      "dashboard_route",
      arguments: "cityName",
    );
```

Then inside dashboard Widget build function, do this to get the cityName:

```
final String cityName = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```